# Receiving 'ToolTip' cannot have a logical or visual parent

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.8

Since updating from .NET 4.61 to .NET 4.8 customers quite regularly receive the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: "ToolTip" kann keine logischen odervisuellen übergeordneten Elemente besitzen.
   bei System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip.OnAncestorChanged()
   bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorChangedInternal(TreeChangeInfo parentTreeState)
   bei System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnAncestorChanged(DependencyObject d, TreeChangeInfo info, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   bei System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   bei MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1._VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   bei System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(FrameworkElement fe, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   bei System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.VisitNode(DependencyObject d, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   bei System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkLogicalChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, FrameworkContentElement fceParent, IEnumerator logicalChildren)
   bei System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.WalkFrameworkElementLogicalThenVisualChildren(FrameworkElement feParent, Boolean hasLogicalChildren)
   bei System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.IterateChildren(DependencyObject d)
   bei System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
   bei MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk(DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
   bei System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnTreeChange(FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyObject parent, Boolean isAddOperation)
   bei System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.UpdatePlacementTargetRegistration(UIElement oldValue, UIElement newValue)
   bei System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.CreateWindow(Boolean asyncCall)
   bei System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.OnIsOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   bei System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
```

This [may occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213901/tooltip-cannot-have-a-logical-or-visual-parent) due to badly defined tooltips.

My problem is: the stacktrace doesn't give any hint **which element** is the cause for this error.

How can I find out what is the source element which caused the exception?

Comment: You could try to trigger all tool tips in your application to find the one(s) that cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions -> Click that you have correct mark.

Now your project stops when exception accours.

Comment: Unfortunately this error occurs on a customer's machine. Therefore it's not possible to debug on this machine.

Comment: Really hard to say, probably someting simple like custom tooltip style problem.